# PowerApps unable to update collection

Tags: powerapps

I am new to Powerapps and probably I am missing something obvious

I am trying to build a "Leave Request" power app from Microsoft template and I want to change below values : Vacation, Sick Leave

[image]

I know that I have to modify them on App (on start value) bookmark- which I did :

[image]

Then I save and leave edit mode.

Once I play it again collection is still the same and values too - I see only change in code

help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gallery you're trying to update is pointing at the RequestorBalanceCollection:
[image]

This collection can be modified on the OnVisible property of the LeaveBalanceScreen:
[image]

Comment: Meaning ? I see here code that works with attribute “requested balance record” which point out to APP main function where I changed it - bear with me . I am new at this :)

Comment: Yeah so this CleaCollect() function is creating a new collection in the app, "RequesterBalanceCollection". This collection will be cleared out and re-created every time a user comes to this screen, because it is on the "OnVisible" property. This collection contains 5 objects, with each of their "type" value being hard coded in and the balance being pulled from the "requesterBlanaceRecord"....Since you already updated the "requesterbalancerecord" you should only need to update the hardcoded "type" values in this ClearCollect function.

Comment: So basically i have to sth like this  ? --->     ClearCollect(RequesterBalanceCollection, 
    { type: "Vacation", balance: Value(_requesterBalanceRecord.Vacation)+16 - Value(_requesterBalanceRecord.VacationUsed)},